# Excel - Copy this row from sheet 1 to next available line in sheet 2 if column H has blank sell

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

If column H has an empty cell then copy that whole row that cell is on onto a new sheet to the next available row, the rows can have any amount of rows so would like this to replicate through every row please.

SHEET1 would have this but potentially hundreds/thousands more rows:

...A.....B.....C......D......E......F......G.....H

data  data  data  data  data  data  data  data

data  data  data  data  data  data  data  data

data  data  data  data  data  data  data

data  data  data  data  data  data  data  data

data  data  data  data  data  data  data  data

data  data  data  data  data  data  data

data  data  data  data  data  data  data  data

data  data  data  data  data  data  data  data

SHEET2 I would like to have this which would be brought through from the first sheet:

...A.....B.....C......D......E......F......G.....H

data  data  data  data  data  data  data

data  data  data  data  data  data  data

Struggling for days to get this right and have tried multiple pieces of code and finally just deleted the whole lot and come on here. Please help anybody :) :) :) :) :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Sub tgr()

    Dim wsSrc As Worksheet  'Variable for Source data worksheet
    Dim wsDst As Worksheet  'Variable for Destination data worksheet

    Set wsSrc = Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set wsDst = Sheets("Sheet2")

    With Intersect(wsSrc.UsedRange, wsSrc.Columns("H"))
        .AutoFilter 1, "="  'Filter for blanks in column H

        'Copy resulting rows to the destination worksheet
        .Offset(1).EntireRow.Copy wsDst.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1)

        .AutoFilter 'Remove the filter
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: This is absolutely amazing, worked first time, thank you. Only other thing I was trying to do was to potentially only filter from line 15 onwards and grab that information. Is there a slight change I can do to this to get that result.

Comment: Change `wsSrc.Column("H")` to `wsSrc.Range("H14:H65000")` 14 so that it treats row 14 as a header row to grab data from row 15 and down. 65000 to use up most of the rows. If your data goes beyond row 65000, just use a bigger number (that does not exceed the last row number).

Comment: Thanks again. Still cannot believe I have missed these answers. Must be getting rusty and need to learn a few things again. Thank you so much for the help, much appreciated.